# What is the Difference Between a Comic and a Graphic Novel?

Tags: comics

This came up in an answer to one of my other questions.  I've been in stores and seen paperbacks called "graphic novels."  Is there a difference between graphic novels and comic books -- other than in length?

Comment: "Graphic novel" is a more palatable term for grown-ups ashamed of liking comics...

Comment: Seems like whenever the publisher decides to collect a complete series of a more "adult" comic, it is called a "trade paperback" and is considered a "graphic novel". I'm not sure about this though.

Comment: In the UK, about 15 quid.

Comment: You could argue that a "graphic novel" is more likely to be standalone (i.e. a whole story), or that they contain stories that are more "adult" in nature, but really Andres F. has it right -- it's often a euphemism for "comics".

Comment: Same question elsewhere with a more detailed answer : http://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/771/how-are-graphic-novels-different-from-comic-books

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience the difference can be a number of things, depending upon the publisher and book store:

- Length (graphic novels are longer),
- Issue rate (comics are issued weekly or monthly, one-offs or compendiums are graphic novels), or
- Target audience (graphic novels are aimed at adults, comics at the teen and afficionado markets).